# angular-moment amDateFormat:'h:mm A z'

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment

Just trying to get named timezone displayed but no luck. Time zone is not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

I have moment.min.js and moment-timezone-with-data.min.js scripts

angular.module('app', ['angularMoment']);

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the amTimezone filter. Otherwise the z will not generate the timezone.

```
{{date | | amDateFormat:"h:mm A z"}} //12:00 AM 

{{date | amTimezone: 'America/New_York' | amDateFormat:"h:mm A z"}} //12:00 AM EST
```

Comment: Also just to add there is `amUtc | amDateFormat` and `amLocal | amDateFormat` for utc timezone vs local timezone